# What permissions are needed to call /{page-id}/ads_posts on Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to list the Ads for a Facebook Page using the Graph API [/{page-id}/ads_posts](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/ads_posts/) endpoint, but I get a permissions when I try to.

Using the Graph API Explorer, I generate an Page Access Token with those permissions: *email*, *read_insights*, *manages_pages*, *pages_show_list*, *ads_read*, *business_management*, *instagram_basic*, *instagram_manage_insights* and *public_profile*.
I'm an admin on the Page itself, the attached Business Manager and on the corresponding Ad Account.

Every time I try to call the /{page-id}/ads_posts, I receive

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) Not enough permission to call this endpoint",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 200,
    "fbtrace_id": "XXXXX"
  }
}
```

I can't find any help on the Facebook documentation or Google, given that the error isn't really meaningful (in some cases, I get a message saying that a specific permissions is missing, but not here). Anyone can help ?

EDIT: I tried to add the *ads_management* permission too, without success.

Comment: For me, the error goes away when I add business_management and ads_management permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add those pages to your app that is in development mode (https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=business_tools).